# Why isn't WM_NCACTIVATE message sent to a Window with its SizeToContent set to Height

Tags: c#, wpf, winapi, windows-messages

I've written a `WndProc` to know if current Window is flashing. It is as follows:

```
    private IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
    {
        var retVal = IntPtr.Zero;

        switch (msg)
        {
            case (int)WindowsMessages.NCACTIVATE:
                retVal = WindowsNative.DefWindowProc(hwnd, WindowsMessages.NCACTIVATE, new IntPtr(1), new IntPtr(-1));
                IsFlashing = (int)wParam == 0;
                break;
        }

        return retVal;
    }
```

Now this is working perfectly with any `Window` except for when their `SizeToContent` property is set to `Height` (I haven't tested `WidthAndHeight` but I assume it won't work either); in which case, the `WM_NCACTIVATE` message is not sent to the `Window` at all. All of my windows are using custom look and feel (using WPF WindowChrome). Do you possibly know the reason or can help me with this problem?

Comment: I wonder if you noticed that `SizeToContent` is prompted in MSDN，you cannot set or get this property when a window is hosted in a browser.

Comment: @StriveSun-MSFT: Hosted in a browser? I didn't mean the browser Chrome, I meant WPF WindowChrome.

Answer (score 0):

In theory, `WM_NCACTIVTE` message events are not blocked for no reason.

If you can, I suggest you redefine `WM_NCACTIVATE`.

like this：

```
    private const uint WM_NCACTIVATE = 0x0086;

    private IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
    {
        var retVal = IntPtr.Zero;

        switch (msg)
        {
            case (int)WindowsMessages.NCACTIVATE:
            retVal = WindowsNative.DefWindowProc(hwnd, WindowsMessages.NCACTIVATE, new IntPtr(1), new IntPtr(-1));
            IsFlashing = (int)wParam == 0;
            break;
        }

    return retVal;
    }
```

Hope to help you.

Comment: So are you suggesting that this problem is because of the constant? I don't think so:
`NCACTIVATE = 0x0086`

Comment: It must be because of some API calls or behaviors `SizeToContent` makes.

Comment: @Javid As far as the code you're posting is concerned, there's no problem with callback functions at least.